# Problem with SQL statement in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, join

I am running an SQL statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT pic, userid 
        FROM user_details 
          INNER JOIN wp_users ON user_details.userid  
        WHERE wp_users.id = user_details.userid 
        LIMIT $recordstart, $pagesize
       ";
```

The query is meant to select records from user_details and wp_users, but should only select if there is a match (`wp_users.id = user_details.userid`).

The target is for it to basically select from a table while retrieving a record (based on the id match) from the other table

The problem is that it shows duplicate records. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What DBMS please? MySQL?

Comment: First, do you know that your query is wrong? That cant' be the one you're running. Also, what do you want to do when there are multiple user_details rows for a user? Just pick one? Or will you not be getting anything from the details at all, just ensuring there are details? Or do you need all the data from many details in a single row (PIVOT)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should put your JOIN condition after ON. Like this:

```
$sql="select pic, userid 
      from user_details 
      inner join wp_users on (wp_users.id=user_details.userid)
      limit $recordstart, $pagesize";
```

But the real problem is that you have more then 1 record in `user_details` for each corresponding record in `wp_users` (or vise versa).
INNER JOIN is causing database to make a [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of `user_details` and `wp_users` records. Then result table is filtered by your current WHERE condition (wp_users.id=user_details.userid). Depends on your needs you can use GROUP BY or DISTINCT if you want to retrieve unique records only. 
For example, if you need `userid` to be unique:

```
$sql="select pic, userid 
      from user_details 
      inner join wp_users on (wp_users.id=user_details.userid)
      group by userid
      limit $recordstart, $pagesize";
```

Comment: Doesn't MySQL support some kind of semi-join (EXISTS)? Using that seems more correct than a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @Erik Yes, there are EXISTS in mysql. But it really depends on what OP is trying to achieve with the query. The question is: what to return if there are 2 user_details for single wp_users?

Comment: Given that he's not selecting any columns from that table and said "only if there is a match", that sure sounds like a semi-join to me! Well, wait... he did say "retrieve a record" so maybe he does need something from the second table. You're right.

Comment: MySQL is the *only* major DB that will accept having the `pic` column not aggregated in a `GROUP BY` query. I find that can lead to hard-to-find bugs. Might be better to say `MAX(pic)` or `MIN(pic)` so that the choice per userid is not arbitrary.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT pic, userid 
FROM user_details 
  INNER JOIN wp_users ON wp_users.id=user_details.userid 
LIMIT $recordstart, $pagesize
```

Comment: The question says he's getting duplicate rows. Maybe you could address that in your answer.

Comment: I have now addressed it with DISTINCT.

Comment: I didn't answer because of the plethora of answers and the questioner's not specifying how he wants to handle multiple child rows. Plus I am not an expert in MySQL. But it would be nice to address the poster's whole question instead of just posting a syntax correction of his query.

Comment: Because of the lack of join criteria I was under the impression he was ending up with a cartesian product of his result set (across all rows in the user_details table).  So fixing the SQL was indeed the solution.  I might be wrong, but I was making an attempt to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use `DISTINCT` to return only unique rows and complete your join condition in the `ON` section:

```
$sql="select distinct pic, userid
      from user_details
      inner join wp_users on wp_users.id=user_details.userid
      limit $recordstart, $pagesize";
```

Comment: Doesn't MySQL support some kind of semi-join (EXISTS)? Using that seems more correct than a `GROUP BY` or a `DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 0):

use GROUP BY , because it shows duplicate records if there is multiple records in second table per on one record in first table

Comment: Doesn't MySQL support some kind of semi-join (EXISTS)? Using that seems more correct than a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: in fact no ( only EXISTS or IN ... , but it isn't join ), because in thery JOIN combines record ( eg. if you have m:n constraint , it will return any availible combination )

Comment: Using EXISTS with an outer reference IS a join. It's called a semi-join or an anti-semi-join.

Answer (score 0):

You left out the = part of the `ON` by accident.

```
$sql="select pic, userid 
      from user_details 
        inner join wp_users on user_details.userid
        = wp_users.id  
      where wp_users.id=user_details.userid   
  limit $recordstart, $pagesize";
```

Comment: The question says he's getting duplicate rows, which you didn't answer. And did you notice the WHERE clause is identical to the ON?

Answer (score 0):

I might try

```
 $sql = "select pic, userid 
 from user_details 
 inner join wp_users on user_details.userid = wp_users.id
 limit $recordstart, $pagesize";
```

Comment: The question says he's getting duplicate rows. Maybe you could address that in your answer.